# Eslint: newline in Arrays/Objects/Function element depending on line size

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am trying to write a custom styleguide for our codebase, stating that there should be line breaks in expression elements (`[]` arrays, `()` arguments, `{}` objects) only if the code line "appears too long" for readability. I'd really like this to be an autofixable rule

I know there is a `minItems` argument for the [*-element-newline](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-element-newline) rule, but I was wondering if I could specify a charlength instead. For instance an array with the same number of items could either be written on one line or several depending on the sum of each elements charlength

```
const shouldBeOneLine = [req, res, middleware, next]
const shouldBeMultiline = [
  request,
  response,
  (token, salt) => salt + Foo.bar(token),
  next
]
```

So far I am relying on the `consistent` argument of the rule, but I still have to manually put linebreaks if the expression becomes too long. I know I could write a plugin for that matter, but it seems to be a common usecase so I'm confident there should already be a solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `max-len` rule that allows you to specify the max number of characters on one line. Unfortunately, it's not auto-fixable. Also, it applies to all code, and not just in arrays, arguments, and objects.

Documentation: [max-len](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len)

There is a discussion on Github regarding the auto-fix implementation for this rule: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11325